# Как реализовать сортировку вставками по признаку четности

Tags: python, сортировка

Задание заключается в модификации типа сортировки вставками. Нам задают список чисел, например:

```
[54, 26, 93, 17, 77, 31, 44, 55, 20]
```

Нам его нужно отсортировать так, чтобы сначала были все четные числа в порядке возрастания, а потом все нечетные в убывающем порядке:

```
[20, 26, 44, 54, 93, 77, 55, 31, 17]
```

Я написал вот такой вот код, но он работает немного не коректно, и я не понимаю почему.

```
def insertionSort(alist):
    for index in range(1, len(alist)):
        currentvalue = alist[index]
        position = index
        if currentvalue % 2 == 0:
            while position > 0 and alist[position - 1] > currentvalue:
                alist[position] = alist[position - 1]
                position = position - 1

                alist[position] = currentvalue

        elif currentvalue % 2 != 0:
            while position < len(alist) - 1 and alist[position + 1] > currentvalue:
                alist[position] = alist[position + 1]
                position = position + 1

                alist[position] = currentvalue
```

Comment: Опишите словами логику алгоритма. Четные числа сортируются в первой половине, а нечетные - начиная с конца?

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka  мы вибираем число и переставляем ето число в право или лево в зависимости от того, четное оно или нет. В конечном итоге должен бить список где сперва парние числа а потом непарние (но непарние идут от большова к маленкому)

Comment: Фактически, ваше условие сводится к тому, что 1) нечетное больше четного 2) четное больше/меньше четного по обычным правилам 3) нечетное больше/меньше нечетного по обратным правилам (descendent sort). Дальше можно применять любой алгоритм сортировки, позволяющий задать функцию сравнения.

Comment: @AlexanderZonor Задание заключаетса в том чтобы модифицировать именно insertionsort

Comment: @Bernard, не вижу тут противоречий с моим комментарием. Выделение компаратора в отдельную функцию повысит понятность, читаемость кода, да и просто техничность решения.

Comment: Вот лог работы 
[54, 26, 93, 17, 77, 31, 44, 55, 20]
1
[26, 54, 93, 17, 77, 31, 44, 55, 20]
2
[26, 54, 93, 17, 77, 31, 44, 55, 20]
3
[26, 54, 93, 77, 31, 44, 55, 20, 17]
4
[26, 54, 93, 77, 44, 55, 31, 20, 17]
5
[26, 54, 93, 77, 44, 55, 31, 20, 17]
6
[26, 54, 93, 77, 44, 55, 31, 20, 17]
7
[20, 26, 54, 93, 77, 44, 55, 31, 17]
8
[20, 26, 54, 93, 77, 44, 55, 31, 17]
как видим, число 44 алгоритмом не обрабатывается. Оно передвигается влево и пропускается.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov я напишу, как вы предлагаете, если не против и запишу в ответ.

Answer (score 3):

```
def cmp(n,m):
    if n==m:
        return 0
    #return 1 if n>m
    # нечетное больше четного
    if n%2==1 and m%2==0:
            return 1
    if n%2==0 and m%2==1:
        return -1

    #нечетное больше нечетного по обратным правилам
    if n%2==1 and m%2==1:
        if n<m:
            return 1
        else:
            return -1

    if n%2==0 and m%2==0:
        if n>m: return 1
        else:return -1

def insertionSort(alist):
    for index in range(1, len(alist)):
        currentvalue = alist[index]
        position = index

        while position > 0 and cmp(alist[position - 1], currentvalue)==1:
            alist[position] = alist[position - 1]
            position = position - 1

            alist[position] = currentvalue

    return alist
```

Answer (score 1):

Еще один ответ не помешает:

```
lst = [54, 26, 93, 17, 77, 31, 44, 55, 20]

def sort_func (a, b):
    if a % 2 == 0:
        if b % 2 == 0:
            return a < b
        return True
    else:
        if b % 2 == 0:
            return True
        return a > b

def insertSort(alist, func):
    if len(alist) == 0: return []
    blist = [alist[0]]
    for i in range(1, len(alist)):
        v = alist[i]
        cond = False
        for j in range(0, len(blist)):
            if not func(blist[j], v):
                blist.insert(j, v)
                break
        else:
            cond = True
        if cond: blist.insert(j+1, v)
    return blist

print(insertSort(lst, sort_func))
```

Результат:

```
[20, 26, 44, 54, 93, 77, 55, 31, 17]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def srt(r):
    if r % 2:
        return False, r
    else:
        return True, - r
lst = [54, 26, 93, 17, 77, 31, 44, 55, 20]
r = sorted(lst, key=srt)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
m = list(map(int, input().split())) # ввод данных
a = [] # новый пустой список куда будем добавлять четные числа
b = [] # новый пустой список куда будем добавлять нечетные числа
for i in m:
    if i % 2 == 0:  #если при делении на 2 нет остатка
        a.append(i) #то добавляем их в новый список 'a'
    else:
        b.append(i) #если есть остаток то добавляем во второй список 'b'
print(sorted(a) + sorted(b)) #сортируем и суммируем два списка
```